# Profiling MacRuby application using Instruments

Tags: xcode, profiling, rubygems, instruments, macruby

I want to port an application to MacRuby to make it easier to distribute as an app, and also be able to use native AppleScript (ScriptingBridge) rather than requiring users have XCode to install binary gem etc. My app relies on bibtex-ruby and citeproc-ruby, and both of these gems are very slow on MacRuby. A benchmark in bibtex-ruby is 100x slower, and even requiring citeproc-ruby takes 4-5 s. I am working with the author of these two gems to find out how to optimize them, and he required the output from ruby-prof. This does not work with MacRuby, but instead, XCode and Instruments has been suggested. I am able to start Instruments, but there is a wealth of options, and I do not know how to configure it so that I can get out useful information about which subroutines are taking most of the time.

How can I use Instruments to profile a MacRuby app with gems? (Or any other approaches welcome too)

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions, not having gone through the need to deal with performance issues from gems:

- If you can isolate the points at which gem functionality (or a gem's specific functionality that's suspect) is invoked, you can insert old-school traces that measure the time before and after the call, then tally them in the log after a few runs.
- If you'd like to use Instruments, you can create a boilerplate objc class that initiates the gem functionality, so you can locate them in the call graph on the time profiler by name, rather than the macruby method addresses.

In both cases, it would probably be useful to understand in detail what kind and level of profile information the developer needs, in order to reproduce profiling information of the same nature with different tools due to your compatibility situation.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is using DTrace, as suggested [here](https://github.com/inukshuk/bibtex-ruby/issues/37#issuecomment-4300320):

Open two terminal windows, in the first one type,
$ your-benchmark-script.rb &,
remember the PID, and then in second window type,
$ sudo dtrace -s path-to-macruby-source/sample-macruby/DTrace/methods_duration.d -p pid.
You may need to add several seconds pause at the beginning of the benchmark script, so you have time to type in the second window.

(there is also methods-count and objects-collected).

Still have not perfectly solved my initial problem, but this added useful information. One problem is that it's not possible to compare execution in MRI and MacRuby, because you cannot use DTrace with MRI (as far as I know).